# Trying to understand surjective and injective

Tags: functions

I'm studying business informatics and right now I need to understand injective and surjective.
I now understand the meaning, I also understand the pictures where the elements of A map to B etc.

My problem is how can I prove this through calculation? To show what I tried and what my problem is:

**Let's say we have:**
$f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R, x\to x^3$

To see if this function is injective/surjective I did the following which I picked up from various videos and texts:

**1. Prove injectivity:**

$x^3=y^3$ | 3rd squareroot

$x=y$

(Because it is $x=y$, it is injective.. I think)

**2. Prove surjectivity:**

$x^3=y$ | 3rd squareroot

$x=\sqrt[3]y$

$f(x) = \left(\sqrt[3]y\right)^3$

$f(x) = y$

(Because $f(x)=y$, the function is surjective)

And because the function is injective and surjective, it is bijective.

My problem is, I don't understand everything because it seems to easy, I guess I am very wrong, that's why I'm here.

*Thank you*

Comment: This is essentially correct.  Compare to the problem of $f~:~x\mapsto x^2$

Comment: @JMoravitz so if I get it correctly, the difference is that:

Injectivity:

For x³ we can reach x=y, for x² that is not possible, here we get multiple x-values.

Surjectivity:
For x³ we can reach f(x)=y, for x² that is not possible, here we get multiple values, the thing that bugs me is -y=y (it sure is one of the reasons that x²  is not surjective but I can't explain in a technical way why that is.)

I hope I'm right, I only did math for the last days I really want to get this.

Thanks for your answer by the way.

Comment: To better understand the formal definitions of injective and surjective for real-valued functions of a single real variable you should tie the definitions to the graphs all you can. For example $f(x)=x^2$ is *not* surjective because you cannot map to or "hit" $-1$ by squaring a real number, and you can see this on the graph by observing that the graph only takes on values such that $y\geq0$ using usual $xy$-space.  If you instead consider this function as mapping $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow Y$ where $Y$ is *non-negative* real values then it IS a surjection, so consider this distinction.

Comment: @AlgTop1854 you mean (what I already noticed) that the range is important in to order say what is injective and surjective. Like talking about R or N could change the outcome of a function being injective/surjective, right?

Comment: Yes exactly although it  has more to do with surjectivity than injectivity. And "range" can be ambiguous - it can be the set that the function maps into without mapping onto, or it can be the image.  For this reason, codomain and image are used more often.  High school math through first year calculus may use range as most of us think of image - but not always!

Comment: Range is the wrong word, I should probably use domain and co-domain. And that is my problem, I get how to prove or identify injectivity/surjectivity but I don't get the meaning behind all of this. If you have anything to make the stuff more understandable to me, like what to read, what to do etc. I would be grateful.